# Permission Denied for VBA Shell Call on Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

We recently upgraded to Windows 10. This VBA code was working in Windows 7 to run a batch script, but now it throws "Run-time error '70': Permission denied.

I've tried several variations of the script, but continue to run into issues. I have Administrator rights on my computer as well. This is on a network drive, but it hasn't been an issue before. Using a cmd prompt, I am able to call this batch file successfully. Any ideas or help you provide would be appreciated.

```
Sub DailyBatchProcess()
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
wsh.Run Chr(34) & "S:\Data\Daily Items\1 Daily Batch\BAT\Transaction Adjustments.bat" & Chr(34), windowStyle, waitOnReturn
Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the error on the `Run` line?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Your new antivirus is using its euristics?

Comment: Fairly certain it's not the antivirus.

Comment: The code below works too, so it seems like it's just a .bat issue. wsh.Run Chr(34) & C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe & Chr(34)